# how to control 3D object of seized resource?

Tags: anylogic

I have a truck agent that seizes a trailer resource from "trailer" resourcepoolblock (thanks to seize block). I want that both the agent both the resource make a rotation in the 3D animation. I did for the agent, while for the resource i tried:
"agent.resourceUnitsOfPool(trailer).trailer1.setRotation(-PI);"
But it does not work. What is the right command in order to control the 3D object of the resource?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[resourceUnitsOfPool](https://anylogic.help/api/com/anylogic/engine/Agent.html#resourceunitsofpool) returns a **list** of all resource agents seized. Assuming you're only seizing a single trailer, you could do the following.

```
agent.resourceUnitsOfPool(trailer).get(0).setRotation(-PI);
```

The above would refer to the agent and set its rotation. If you want to rotate a Shape3D object within the agent, just refer to it after the `get(0)`.

Or you could use [resourceUnitOfPool](https://anylogic.help/api/com/anylogic/engine/Agent.html#resourceunitofpool) (which I assume you were trying to use. Notice **unit**, singular), which returns the first occurrence of resource unit of a given pool among the seized resource units, and then proceed in a similar manner.

Comment: I used a different method. I created a Trailer type  parameter in the truck agent and ,on seize unite section, the seize block has the following code "agent.trailer= (Trailer) unit."